# free magento 1 to magento 2 migration tool?

Tags: magento2, magento-1

Does anyone know a free magento 1 to magento 2 migration tool? I found some but they are partially free, that is, after a certain amount you have to pay.

Answer (score 0):

There is an official tool from magento for migrating data from magento 1 to magento 2:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/migration-tool.html

Comment: Does this method seem to be too complex, or could I be wrong?

Comment: That depends on the data I guess - you shouldnt try it in a production environment, but maybe you can test it in a local magento2 environment

Answer (score 0):

you should use Store Manager at least trial, cause it eases the export/import of entities. With the default migration you should also take aspirin and be ready to be missing around a week or so:)))